# Error wp-cron.php wysija_cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel

I'm facing the following error in Error Log messages

```
[Sun Sep 03 06:42:36.131526 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 1047562:tid 140001614550784] [client 37.61.238.59:57930] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/syriacar/public_html/wp-cron.php, referer: http://syria-cart.com/wp-cron.php?fe9a4e6677a8143b25dc814f5f08d768&action=wysija_cron&process=queue,bounce&silent=1
```

what does it means any how can I solve it?

Comment: If you're uisng Apache try to access `httpd.conf`, and show what are the `<Directory />` directives

Comment: I couldn't find it in cpanel